# How can I get play.db.ebean.Model working on my new PlayFramework project?

Tags: model, playframework-2.0, ebean

I've started a play framework project, using console. All was built seemingly OK.

My `project/plugins.sbt` file is

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(PlayEbean). Note, uncommenting this line will automatically bring in
// Play enhancer, regardless of whether the line above is commented out or not.
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

I uncommented the line before the last as an attempt to make ebean work.

and my `build.sbt` file is

```
name := """whatever"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator


fork in run := true
```

Where, on 
`lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)`

On my `conf/application.conf` I have already added the DB connections strings and defined where ebean should default to.

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/whatever?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=whatever 
db.default.password=whateverUser

ebean.default="models.*"
```

I added the 'PlayEbean' part.

On the activator console, I do clean, compile, eclipse. Remove the project from eclipse and re-import it.

When I try to start using this 'high-productivity' framework I get stuck on the first model I'm trying to build.

[image: eclipse problem importing ebean dependency]

What am I getting wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have never used ebean myself but according to [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean) `play.db.ebean.Model` should be `com.avaje.ebean.Model`.

Comment: @Roman Yes! It worked! Please submit as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ebean support has been extracted into its own project with the release of play 2.4. Hence `play.db.ebean.Model` does not exist anymore. Use `com.avaje.ebean.Model` instead.